# Passenger + RVM + ubuntu 11.04 server == problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, passenger

Ok so i have a new amazon ubuntu 11.04 ec2 instance and all seems great other then passenger and ruby and rvm. OK so my apache2.conf has this

```
    LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11
    PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/ruby

    # PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
    #LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@crm/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c
    #PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@crm/gems/passenger-3.0.11
```

I have some commented out because I have tried all kinds of variations to get rvm and passenger to work together .

my vhost is this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin something@gmail.com
    ServerName logicxl.com
    # ServerAlias
    DocumentRoot /srv/crm/current/public
    ErrorLog /srv/crm/logs/error.log

      <Directory "/srv/crm/current/public">
         Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the url is [logicxl.com](http://logicxl.com/) but as you can see there is the rake error

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

but i did bundle install and got this

```
/srv/crm/current$ bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
....
....
....
Using thin (1.3.1) 
Using uglifier (1.2.2) 
Using unicorn (4.1.1) 
Using will_paginate (3.0.2) 
Using yajl-ruby (1.1.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

so the gems are installed but the error persists....I am assuming there is a problem with which ruby is being used and what gems are being used...but i have tried almost everything to get this to work...any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried performing a system-wide RVM install (it's just like a regular install, but logged in as root)?

Also, try to deploy your application using Capistrano ([with RVM support](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/)) instead of manually copying files and running `bundler`. There are plenty of tutorials about it. It will make sure you install your gem dependencies correctly.

Comment: i am deploying with capistrano....but how do i do it with with RVM support and also how do i do a system wide install of rvm ...i thought i installed it

Comment: As I said on my answer, a system-wide install is just like a regular install, but you start it logged in as root. Try to implode your current RVM (using `rvm implode`) and reinstall while logged in as root.

Comment: And to add RVM support for your Capistrano recipe, read: http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/

Answer (score 0):

find whether rake-0.9.2.2 gem is in your /home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/ruby path, I think the problem is passenger ruby cannot find rake gem globally, trying gem install rake -v=0.9.2.2